# What hex colorcode for grey, is the HTC Sense theme using?

Tags: android, htc-android, htcsense

What hex colorcode for grey,
is the HTC Sense theme using ?

Comment: Why don't you take a screenshot and use the eyedropper tool of your favorite image editing software to find out?

Comment: That, or you look at the Sense source.

Comment: What bit of Sense UI are you referring to?

Comment: @EboMike, the HTC Sense source? Where is it available (not counting in reverse-engineering)?

Comment: @EboMike, I would like to look at the Sense source, but I don't have it...

Comment: @lucero: I never looked myself, I based that on regular news of HTC releasing the source for their phones here (which is here http://developer.htc.com/). But now that I look at it, I suppose that it's a different layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `#f7f9f6` ! i picked this from the Clock background ! just tell me exactly which grey of the theme do you want ?

PS. You really can't find a color cause most of it got a gradient effect.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is better to build applications that [adapt to the current system theme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes), than to try to match a specific theme in your app's theme. There is [a thread here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229622/android-application-theming-on-sense-phones) about how this applies to Sense UI; I can not comment on this myself as I have no relevant experience.

Comment: I'm currently using <color name="title_background">#CCCCCC</color> as background for all my activities. How would I adapt this to the current system theme ?

Comment: There is an example on referencing system style attributes in my first link. For your specific case, I think this attribute may be what you're looking for: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowBackground